# Rear gears don't turn anticlockwise

Tags: mountain-bike, gears

I've taken the rear wheel off my bike but the rear gears are stuck and do not spin freely anticlockwise.

It had been out of use for about 4 days, kept in a dry garage. I took the wheel off because it was bent, then found this problem.

Any idea what's happened or if i can fix it?

Comment: Was the wheel normal before you took it from the bike? Or you took it BECAUSE it got stuck? Was it sudden? Was the bike stored, out of use, for a long time? Possibly it took some rain? More details are needed!

Answer (score 4):

Well, the freewheel/freehub is frozen, apparently.  Generally nothing to do but replace that component (repair is possible but difficult).

But there are two other possibilities:

1. Look between the big gear and the hub to make sure there's nothing (eg, a pebble) jammed in there.
2. The nuts on the axle (including some you can't see) may have somehow become overtightened.  You can try loosening the nuts you *can* see and see if that improves things, but you might as well take the wheel to your local bike shop since they have the tools to take it apart and know how to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably rust and/or old grease inside the cassette.

I would try spraying WD40 into the freewheel, waiting overnight, and trying to "break it free" the other day.

But there could be other problems, like the ones Daniel Hicks cited. It would be fine to add more detail to your question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It had been out of use for about 4 days. kept in a dry garage.
I took the wheel off because it was bent, then found this problem.


I will try WD40 tonight thanks.

sorry about the lack of info, hope you've got all you need to know now.

Comment: @JeremyHughes -- How did the wheel get bent?  What did you do to fix it?

Comment: wheel was bent because i do alot of off roading, it's only a slight kink, the bike was still very rideable.
i bought a new wheel, but i have not fitted it yet.